# Query data from an API onto page in Node & Express without page refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

I currently have a form on my website that a user can fill out and then return information to the page. The page refreshes and I am wondering if this is possible without the need for a complete page refresh, but still have the data auto update.

## View

```
doctype html
html
    head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    body
    form(name="yelp-form", method="post")
        div.input
            span.label City
            input(type="text", name="city")
            span.label  Search Term
            input(type="text", name="term")
        div.actions
            input(type="submit", value="add")
    block content
```

## Route

```
router.post('/', function(req, res){
    var businesses = [];
    if(req.body.city === '' || req.body.term === ''){
      res.render('api', {title: 'LocateMyCoffee', businesses: businesses});
    }
    // console.log(req.body);
    // console.log(req);
    yelp.search({location: req.body.city, term: req.body.term, category_filter: "food"}, function(error, data) {
        var test = JSON.stringify(data); //Changes yelps response to JSON Objects with double quotes
        test = JSON.parse(test); //JSON.parse can now parse correctly after stringify is used.
        // for(var i = 0; i < ; i++){
        // Uncomment line below to return every business that matches query.
        if(test['businesses'].length < 9){
          cycles = test['businesses'].length;
        }else{
          cycles = 9;
        }

        for(var i = 0; i < cycles; i++){
            var tempObject = {
              name_information: test['businesses'][i]['name'],
              imgur: test['businesses'][i]['rating_img_url'],
              phone: test['businesses'][i]['display_phone']
            };
           businesses.push(tempObject);
        };

        console.log(test['businesses'][0]);

        res.render('api', {title: 'LocateMyCoffee', businesses: businesses});

    }); //End Yelp Search
  });

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: For a small number of information exchange, you may try ajax using javascript. Most people use jquery for that.

Comment: I guess I'm not quite sure how to implement that